# Get JSON array of rows with MySQL

Tags: mysql, arrays, json

I want that MySQL will return a result set in a form of JSON array.

A worked query:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(
    '[',
        GROUP_CONCAT(
            JSON_OBJECT(
                'ProductId', tblproducts.ProductId,
                'ProductName', tblproducts.ProductName
            )
        ),
    ']') As Products
FROM tblproducts;
```

This query returns the following JSON array:

```json
[
    {
        "ProductId": "1",
        "ProductName": "Milk"
    },
    {
        "ProductId": "2",
        "ProductName": "Bread"
    }
]
```

Although this code works, I have a strong feeling that building a JSON array with `GROUP_CONCAT` and `CONCAT` is kind of workaround. If to use a `JSON_ARRAY`, a result set will consist of JSON arrays for each `JSON_OBJECT`.

Is there any native way to get a single JSON array with all `JSON_OBJECT` in the result set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`JSON_ARRAYAGG()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg) could be what you're looking for.

```sql
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(
    JSON_OBJECT(
        'ProductId', tblproducts.ProductId,
        'ProductName', tblproducts.ProductName
    )
) FROM tblproducts;
```

Here's an example: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uQ9UC7MDZM4gncNjViTsKw/0